# Estimate the sum of predicted variables by a linear model in R

Tags: r, least-squares, prediction, prediction-interval

I have a dataset with 3000 sub-regions with data about their population by income range and their value spending in a commodity. I made a OLS model with log-log transformation using `lm()` function in R to predict the spending in another 300 sub-regions.

$$
\ln(Y+1) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\ln(X_1+1) + \beta_2\ln(X_2+1) + ... + \epsilon
$$

Where $Y$ is the aggregated spending by the sub-region, and the $X$'s are the Population by income range.

In R:

```
myModel = lm(log(spending + 1) ~ log(pop_income1 + 1) + log(pop_income2) +
           log(pop_income3 + 1) + log(pop_income4 + 1), data=myOldData)
```

Then I use `predict(myModel, myNewData, interval = "prediction")`.

But this resulted in the expected value of $\ln(Y_i+1)$ and its predictions intervals for every $i$ and I need the prediction interval and mean of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i$, where $n$ is 300.

How can I do that with R?

Comment: (i) if you're writing a distribution for predicted values it sounds like you're trying to use a Bayesian framework. Are you after a prediction interval for your predicted values (or their sum) instead? (ii) when you're exponentiating the log scale predictions, what quantity, exactly, are you trying to produce an estimate of?

Comment: (i) I'm trying to estimate their sum.
(ii) The quantity that I'm trying to estimate is a spending on a  commodity.

Comment: In respect of (i) the question was asking if you want a prediction interval, not asking if you want a sum (I don't care in that part whether you want sums or individual predictions, which is why I mention both; I was trying to find out whether it's a Bayesian question - as asked - or a frequentist question - as it sounds like you probably mean to ask). (ii) The quantity (the sum) is a random variable. Were you after a mean, a median (which is what you're apparently  computing an estimate of, whether you mean to or not), or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand you. (i) I want the prediction interval of the sum. (ii) the mean.

Comment: Could you edit to reflect this information?

Comment: Edit done. Put the R code, the formula, and the type of data I'm using to make the predictions. I thing it's pretty clear what I need now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to produce predictions on the levels of a variable $Y_i$ for a linear
regression that is fitted to the logarithms of the variable
$$
\log Y_i = \boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta} + \varepsilon_i
$$
where $ \mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i \mid \boldsymbol{X}_i) = 0$.

### Option 1:

One option is
$$
\begin{align}
\widehat{Y}_i &= \overline{\exp(\widehat{\varepsilon})}\exp\left(\widehat{\log Y} _i\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\overline{\exp(\widehat{\varepsilon})}$ is the sample mean of the exponentiated residuals from the log-normal fit.

A theoretical justification proceeds by noting that the log-normal regression implies that
$$
\begin{align}
Y_i &= \exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta} + \varepsilon_i\right) \\
Y_i &= \exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)\exp(\varepsilon_i) 
\end{align}
$$

Under conditional indepedence of the errors and the covariates, we can write
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_i \mid \boldsymbol{X}_i) = \exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)\mathbb{E}(\exp(\varepsilon_i)) 
$$

We will need estimates of $\exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)$ and  $\mathbb{E}(\exp(\varepsilon_i))$ in order to construct estimates of $\mathbb{E}(Y_i \mid \boldsymbol{X}_i)$. 
A consistent estimator of $\mathbb{E}(\exp(\varepsilon_i))$ is $\overline{\exp(\widehat{\varepsilon})}$. Combining this information, we get that a theoretically justifiable 
estimator of $\mathbb{E}(Y_i \mid \boldsymbol{X}_i)$ is
$$
\widehat{Y}_i  = \exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i'\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\overline{\exp(\widehat{\varepsilon})}
$$

#### R implementation:

This can be easily coded in R.

```
data(longley)

# log-linear regression
lmLongley = lm(log(GNP) ~ GNP.deflator + Armed.Forces + Population, 
               data = longley)

# compute the predictions
predGNPLevel = exp(predict(lmLongley))*mean(exp(resid(lmLongley)))

# print the output
cbind(predGNPLevel, longley$GNP)
```

### Option 2:

The second option follows if we assume that the errors in the log-linear regression follow a normal distribution $N(0, \sigma^2)$, then $\exp(\varepsilon_i)$ follows a log-normal distribution, with mean $\exp(\sigma^2/2)$. This implies that
 $$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y_i \mid \boldsymbol{X}_i) &= \exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)\mathbb{E}(\exp(\varepsilon_i))  \\
&= \exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)\exp(\sigma^2/2)  
\end{align}
$$

Plugging in consistent estimates of $\sigma^2$ produces the predictions
$$
\widehat{Y}_i  = \exp\left(\boldsymbol{X}_i'\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\exp(\widehat{\sigma^2}/2)
$$

#### R implementation:

The R implementation is again straighforward:

```
predGNPLevel2 = exp(predict(lmLongley))*exp(var(resid(lmLongley))/2)

# print the output
cbind(predGNPLevel2, longley$GNP)
```

Comment: I was looking for the estimation of the sum of this variables.

I have about 10 regions and 3000 sub-regions. For some additional 300 sub-regions that forms a region I predict the log of spending in a commodity as the log of its population by income range using a OLS model estimated with the 3000 sub-regions data. I have these predictions and their confidence intervals. What I want is the prediction and interval confidence for the total spending of the region, i.e., the sum of the 300 sub-regions. Its distribution would be also useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the distribution is symmetric on the log-scale (and the mean exists), then when you exponentiate the predictions, you're getting an estimate of the median, not the mean (quantiles carry over under monotonic transformations, moments don't).

In fact by Jensen's inequality, your prediction is biased downward.

For the moment, let's ignore that you're dealing with a sum and worry about a single prediction. I'll come back to the sum of values in a minute.

Let's assume normality on the log-scale.

(a) taking the variance parameter as known

In this case, your predicted mean values (as fg nu suggests above) are $\exp(\hat y + ½ \sigma_y^2)$ (taking $\sigma^2=s^2$), or better, if you take into account the uncertainty in $\hat y$, $\exp(\hat y + ½ \sigma_{y-\hat y}^2)$, where $\sigma_{y-\hat y}^2$ is the variance of a prediction on the log scale.

Your prediction intervals (for observations, not CIs for the mean) here (constructed via pivotal quantity, for example) will be based on lognormal distributions.

(b) variance parameter is unknown.

Here you have a problem, because the distributions become log-t. You don't have *any* finite moments, not even the mean.

You can still construct a prediction interval here just fine - the quantiles still exist.

(c) dealing with sums (I have to go now, I'll have to come back and do this case)